# Displaying blog entries with identical google maps

Tags: google-maps

You can see my problem here:link deleted
Basically I can not display the full text of my posts on the front page because the maps will conflict.

These are the expanded posts that right now I am displaying as collapse on my front page

link deleted

link deleted

As soon as I display them expanded the maps overlap
Changing the map name variable in the code does not solve the problem, neither changing the name of the  where I display the maps (right now they are the same but I tried that)

Question: I do realize that when I display two maps on the same page there will be two "iniktialize" functions.  Also the two pages have identical java script function names. How do I deal with these ?

Answer (score 1):

> I do realize that when I display two maps on the same page there will be two "iniktialize" functions. Also the two pages have identical java script function names. How do I deal with these ?

You can't have multiple functions with the same name (the browser will pick one version and us it, different browsers might pick different versions).  Either give them different names, or if they do the same thing with different data, use the parameters passed in to give you the unique behavior.

Comment: I guess I will have to try that if there is no other way. What do I do with initialize ? Since these are blog entries I need one initialize function for each blog entry but when I display both articles on the front page the two functions will conflict. How can I solve this ? Thanks

Comment: Pass a parameter or parameters to the initialize function based on the particular page (or blog entry) that lets the function determine what to initialize.  I would suggest using arrays to keep references.