# Two Google Maps displaying on one page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

Trying to display two maps on one page. I've managed to get both displayed but can only drop second map pin...I think the second map is overwriting the first pin but need help

```
<script>
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.059955, -114.211807);

    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: myCenter,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: 'http://www.fergusandbix.com/images/FB-pin.png'
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    var myCenter2 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.9156772, -113.9640719);

    function initialize() {
        var mapProp2 = {
            center: myCenter2,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP2
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap2"), mapProp2);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter2,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: 'http://www.fergusandbix.com/images/FB-pin.png'
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: In your `mapProp2` should the mapTypeId be `google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP` instead of `...ROADMAP2`?

Comment: Well you have two functions named `initialize`, the second ovewrites the first one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying blog entries with identical google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358507/displaying-blog-entries-with-identical-google-maps)

Comment: thanks yuriy636, Nicholas Smith...both have helped clean up the code but still yield the same result. I agree that one is canceling out the other but...not entirely sure how not to have that happen. Removing the second initialize doesn't remove the issue...thakns again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create multiple `initialize` functions, put the relevant content in a single function.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ohtdjqt9/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.059955, -114.211807);
var myCenter2 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.9156772, -113.9640719);

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: 'http://www.fergusandbix.com/images/FB-pin.png'
  });
  marker.setMap(map);

  var mapProp2 = {
    center: myCenter2,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP2
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap2"), mapProp2);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter2,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: 'http://www.fergusandbix.com/images/FB-pin.png'
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

#googleMap,
#googleMap2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

#googleMap {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
<div id="googleMap2"></div>
```